# Why is the UI is different across the different SE websites?

Tags: discussion, design

I am on several SE websites and I am wondering why the UI differs?

In my opinion, this is a little bit disturbing!

Answer (score 2):

The UI is different on every (graduated) Stack Exchange site.

For example:

- https://photo.stackexchange.com/
- https://android.stackexchange.com/
- https://diy.stackexchange.com/

It is only the beta sites that share the same UI.

For example:

- https://ell.stackexchange.com/
- https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

It's one of the rewards for graduating from beta through to full site.

What exactly is it about this design that you find disturbing?

Comment: I think that it makes the navigation across those different websites less consistent ! I perfectly understand that some elements should be different (to help the user to distinguish the different websites) but for me, some elements of the UI (like the vote arrows etc...) should be left the same.

Comment: But in my opinion there are some differences that are even worse, for example, on SE Photography, I think that the position of the navigation links is too different than the usual !

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Photography is a special case I think, because of the photo of the day thing. They actually did a lot of work sort of recently making the top bar unified across all SE sites. The basic intent is for the UI to structurally be the same, but visually be unique communities (because they are)

Comment: @BenBrocka Oh it reassures me ! :)